# How to put a response in an html form with javascript array and a button to get the response in the form field

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I have a js array and I wanted to log a random song into a HTML form when the button (named song) is pressed. I can log it into the console but I can't figure out how to use document.getElementById (I'm new to JS so please bear with me). I appreciate any help.

JavaScript:

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
function randSong() {
var listOfSongs = ['Killomanjaro','No Sad No Bad','Doomsday','Solitaire',
'Distance','Roll In Peace','Bank Account','SAD!','Moonlight','Swimming Pools'];
console.log('Alexa, play',listOfSongs[i]);
}
randSong();
```

HTML:

```
<form>
      Random Song:<input type="text" id="RandSong" name="song"/>
      <input type="button" value="Song" onclick="randSong()"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: If I understand your question. you want to put the name of the song into your textbox?  `document.getElementById('RandSong').value = listOfSongs[i];`

Comment: If you want to select a random song each time you click the button, your `var i` should be inside the `randSong()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
function randSong() {
var listOfSongs = ['Killomanjaro','No Sad No Bad','Doomsday','Solitaire',
'Distance','Roll In Peace','Bank Account','SAD!','Moonlight','Swimming Pools'];
console.log('Alexa, play',listOfSongs[i]);
document.getElementById('RandSong').value = listOfSongs[i];
}
randSong();
```

This should do it.  Also, get rid of the +1 when you set the value for i.  Math.random will return between 0 and 1.  Arrays start at 0, so the way you wrote it could result in getting a 10, which would be out of the range.